# Why does SQLSetStmtAttr have StringLength set to 0

Tags: sql-server, database, odbc

In the example

```
#define ROW_ARRAY_SIZE 10  

// Define the ORDERINFO struct and allocate an array of 10 structs.  
typedef struct {  
   SQLUINTEGER   OrderID;  
   SQLINTEGER    OrderIDInd;  
   SQLCHAR       SalesPerson[11];  
   SQLINTEGER    SalesPersonLenOrInd;  
   SQLCHAR       Status[7];  
   SQLINTEGER    StatusLenOrInd;  
} ORDERINFO;  
ORDERINFO OrderInfoArray[ROW_ARRAY_SIZE];  

SQLULEN    NumRowsFetched;  
SQLUSMALLINT   RowStatusArray[ROW_ARRAY_SIZE], i;  
SQLRETURN      rc;  
SQLHSTMT       hstmt;  

// Specify the size of the structure with the SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_TYPE  
// statement attribute. This also declares that row-wise binding will  
// be used. Declare the rowset size with the SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE  
// statement attribute. Set the SQL_ATTR_ROW_STATUS_PTR statement  
// attribute to point to the row status array. Set the  
// SQL_ATTR_ROWS_FETCHED_PTR statement attribute to point to  
// NumRowsFetched.  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_TYPE, sizeof(ORDERINFO), 0);  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, 0);  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_STATUS_PTR, RowStatusArray, 0);  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROWS_FETCHED_PTR, &NumRowsFetched, 0);  

// Bind elements of the first structure in the array to the OrderID,  
// SalesPerson, and Status columns.  
SQLBindCol(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &OrderInfoArray[0].OrderID, 0, &OrderInfoArray[0].OrderIDInd);  
SQLBindCol(hstmt, 2, SQL_C_CHAR, OrderInfoArray[0].SalesPerson,  
            sizeof(OrderInfoArray[0].SalesPerson),  
            &OrderInfoArray[0].SalesPersonLenOrInd);  
SQLBindCol(hstmt, 3, SQL_C_CHAR, OrderInfoArray[0].Status,  
            sizeof(OrderInfoArray[0].Status), &OrderInfoArray[0].StatusLenOrInd);  

// Execute a statement to retrieve rows from the Orders table.  
SQLExecDirect(hstmt, "SELECT OrderID, SalesPerson, Status FROM Orders", SQL_NTS);  

// Fetch up to the rowset size number of rows at a time. Print the actual  
// number of rows fetched; this number is returned in NumRowsFetched.  
// Check the row status array to print only those rows successfully  
// fetched. Code to check if rc equals SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO or  
// SQL_ERRORnot shown.  
while ((rc = SQLFetchScroll(hstmt,SQL_FETCH_NEXT,0)) != SQL_NO_DATA) {  
   for (i = 0; i < NumRowsFetched; i++) {  
      if (RowStatusArray[i] == SQL_ROW_SUCCESS|| RowStatusArray[i] ==   
         SQL_ROW_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {  
         if (OrderInfoArray[i].OrderIDInd == SQL_NULL_DATA)  
            printf(" NULL      ");  
         else  
            printf("%d\t", OrderInfoArray[i].OrderID);  
         if (OrderInfoArray[i].SalesPersonLenOrInd == SQL_NULL_DATA)  
            printf(" NULL      ");  
         else  
            printf("%s\t", OrderInfoArray[i].SalesPerson);  
         if (OrderInfoArray[i].StatusLenOrInd == SQL_NULL_DATA)  
            printf(" NULL\n");  
         else  
            printf("%s\n", OrderInfoArray[i].Status);  
      }  
   }  
}  

// Close the cursor.  
SQLCloseCursor(hstmt);
```

(from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/row-wise-binding)

SQLSetStmtAttr has the value of 0 for StringLength.

```
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_BIND_TYPE, sizeof(ORDERINFO), 0);  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, ROW_ARRAY_SIZE, 0);  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROW_STATUS_PTR, RowStatusArray, 0);  
SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_ROWS_FETCHED_PTR, &NumRowsFetched, 0);
```

However, according to the documentation:

> If ValuePtr is a pointer to a character string, then StringLength is
>   the length of the string or SQL_NTS.
>
> If ValuePtr is a pointer to a binary buffer, then the application
>   places the result of the SQL_LEN_BINARY_ATTR(length) macro in
>   StringLength. This places a negative value in StringLength.
>
> If ValuePtr is a pointer to a value other than a character string or a
>   binary string, then StringLength should have the value SQL_IS_POINTER.
>
> If ValuePtr contains a fixed-length value, then StringLength is either
>   SQL_IS_INTEGER or SQL_IS_UINTEGER, as appropriate.

There does not seem to be an option to have it set to 0 unless ValuPtr is a zero length array.

What am I missing?